# Twitter Bootstrap Image Centring With Overlay

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get a centered image that spans the entire page, with a small text box overlay. You can see my attempt at [www.cloudtute.com](http://www.cloudtute.com).

Unfortunately this doesn't work in all browsers and the form elements look weird in some browsers. E.g. trying it in internet explorer 9 it comes up tiled and the text box is black!

I was trying to go for a similar effect to the image on [www.airbnb.com](http://www.airbnb.com) which works in all browsers - can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong please?

Answer (score 0):

From what you've explained it shouldnt be too difficult. However www.cloudtute.com isnt opening for me, it comes up with not found, so I cant see your code. If you can add your current code or get the website working again I can help out.